# In Universal Control, is there any way to switch focus from macOS to the iPad with a keystroke, rather than having to push through with the mouse?

Tags: macos, ipad, ipados, universal-control

In Universal Control, in order to start writing on my iPad, I have to switch focus by selecting something with the mouse, then the keyboard keystrokes will be sent to the iPad.

In order to switch back, I have to reach for the mouse again.

Is there any way to switch focus back and forth with the keyboard alone?

An option that includes the apps running on my iPad in the Cmd + Tab app selector would also work great, maybe a custom app switcher does that?

Comment: The pointer is the only element that can “push through” between screens. How is macOS/iOS supposed to know which keystrokes are for which device unless you shift focus?

Comment: yes, what I'm asking is if there's a "shift focus" keystroke, similar to how you can shift focus with `Tab` between elements of a window, or with `Cmd` + `Tab` between opened apps, is there a keystroke that shifts focus between devices?

Comment: You’re not moving between spaces where something like Mission Control would come into play, you’re *switching between devices seamlessly* and at present, only the mouse can facilitate  that.